# Asymptotic behavior of a sequence based on a subsequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Let $c\in(0,1)$, $m\geq 1$ be positive integer and $\{a_{n}\}$ a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers. Suppose that $$a_{n^{m}}\leq K c^{n}n^{-m/2}, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}, $$for some  $K>0$. How to describe the behavior of the whole sequence $\{a_{n}\}$?

Answer (score 0):

Since the sequence is decreasing,
$$ a_i \leq a_j $$
for $j \leq i$. Putting in the inequality given, we have
$$ a_i \leq K \min_{n^m \leq i} c^n n^{-m/2}. $$
For fixed $m$, we can take $n = \lfloor i^\frac{1}{m} \rfloor$, and plugging this into the inequality yields
$$ a_i \leq K \frac{c^{\lfloor i^\frac{1}{m} \rfloor}}{\lfloor i^\frac{1}{m} \rfloor^{m/2}}. $$

Comment: But $m$ is a fixed number. Also the final estimate seems to be very  "slow" . I'm working in some ideas....tkx anyway!

Comment: I didn't realize that $m$ is supposed to be fixed. I'll update my answer when I get a chance.